# Dialog Box action using selenium

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After posting information in my webapp, I get this warning dialog box

"Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.

Are you sure you want to continue?

```
      <button> Continue         <button> Cancel
```

How do I select "Continue" using selenium. Already tried for Conformation and alert, not working.

Answer (score 2):

If its a windows dialog box use the following code

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Is it a window?? In that case try following:

```
String winHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); //Get current window handle.
for(String windowsHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
     driver.switchTo().window(windowsHandle); //Iterate to the new window handle.
}
/*
Do any action on window or just close it.
*/
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); //Switch to original window.
```

See if it helps you.

Comment: Its not a window, its a browser generated security warning dialog box.

Comment: For Alert, selenium gives an error "There were no alerts". I guess its doesn't see Browser generated warnings as alert, although I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try keyboard actions instead:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

private void handleWindow(boolean continue)
{
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    if (continue)
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
    else
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
}
```